# Why does the condition evaluation make no sense?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-logic-apps

I created a logic app that is triggered by any new user stories created, and there is a condition that checks if the story is unparented (no parent linked), then it should notify the user in teams.

The condition logic is if PARENT equals to 0 that means notify user, else FALSE (nothing happens). However, this is not working as the expression keeps evaluating to false and thus nothing happens, despite the user story having no parent linked. I also tested this with a user story with a linked parent and it evaluates to false too.

So then I switched the condition to PARENT is NOT equal to 0, and this evaluates to true for both new stories with NO parent linked and stories with parent linked! How does that make any sense?

What I'm thinking is the value it's expecting is likely a string since the PARENT field I assume is a string? If so, what should the value be then if not integer?

[image: condition]

[image: condition evaluation]

[image: no parent]

I thought to change the condition to use related work however there's only related link count field and related link could be a task which isn't what we are requiring here, rather, we want to notify if the user story has NO parent linked.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but it sounds like if the item doesn't have a parent, it must be something other than 0 (NULL? -1?)

Comment: @BryanWilliams tried NULL and also -1, both still yield a false evaluation with condition (parent is equal to NULL/-1). Created new story with no parent linked, so the expression was supposed to evaluate to true, however, still evaluated to false.

Comment: Sorry you haven't figured this out yet. I'm watching because I would like to know too. For DevOps conditions, it works if you check for "Parent=" and leave the ID blank, but I don't know about Logic Apps. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reproducing from my end, I observed that the parent will be recorded as "null" when there is no parent is linked to the current work item. Below is my logic app flow.

[image]

Code view for the condition

```
"and": [
                        {
                            "equals": [
                                "@body('Get_work_item_details')?['fields']?['System_Parent']",
                                "@null"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
```

*RESULTS WHEN PARENT ISN'T LINKED*

[image]

*RESULTS WHEN PARENT IS LINKED*

[image]

Comment: life saver, thank you so much! setting it zto null dynamic expression did the trick!